# Print name of MongoDB collections with Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to print the names of the MongoDB collections in my database. But when I run my code I get this response back:

```
DB Collections: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0499F550>
```

This is my code:

```
def print_collections(my_db,instance_col):
    x = my_db.instance_col.find()
    print(f"DB Collections: {x}")
```

How can I get the names of the collections instead of printing the mongodb cursor?

Comment: Try `    x = list(my_db.instance_col.find())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the cursor in the print statement error you can do the following:

```
x = [obj for obj in x]
```

This is needed because cursor is an iterator and values are made available upon iteration.

But, this code will find all documents in the collection with name : `instance_col`. To list all the collections you can do the following:

```
print(my_db.collection_names())
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am just trying to list the collection names. That worked.